# Bower does not download dist folder

Tags: visual-studio, jquery-validate, bower

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and creating a test MVC application.
I have added bower file (`bower.json`) with code as follows:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "jquery-validation":"1.15.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery-validation": ">=1.8"
  }
}
```

When I save the `bower.json`, it downloads all correctly, but for jquery-validation it does not download the dist folder:

[image]

Comment: I dont know if this is the correct approach but I downloaded jquery-validation files and manually added dist folder into my project. It's working fine for me at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I also did the same..

Comment: This happens with empty project. Try building the package to download all files.